# "Tanático" no está en el DLE?

Tags: vocabulario, palabras-raras, dle

Estoy leyendo un libro en el que aparece la palabra "tanático", la cual he intentado buscar tanto en el DLE online como en la app WordReference. No se encuentra en ninguno de los dos.

He encontrado el significado [aquí](https://www.significadode.org/tan%C3%A1tico.htm):

> Pulsión de muerte, relativo a la muerte. Es una palabra que proviene del nombre de la deidad griega Tánatos.
>
> "Cada vez que tengo que inventar un ejemplo siento un impulso tanático."

Esto me ha sorprendido, ya que siempre había pensado que el DLE es la referencia más completa de la lengua española. Es decir, que contiene "todas las palabras". ¿Una creencia un poco ingenua?  Si no lo es, ¿hay una mejor?

Comment: Cerulean, por favor, debes incluir el contexto.  La frase en el libro, que contiene la palabra. //  En general yo diría que ningún diccionario puede ser suficiente, por más bueno que sea.

Comment: @aparente001 desgraciadamente he devuelto el libro a la biblioteca -- la próxima vez!

Comment: ¿Acaso tienes el título y autor?

Comment: https://www.herdereditorial.com/en-el-enjambre_1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tanático viene de [*Tánatos*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%A1natos#Psicoan%C3%A1lisis) + *-ico*. La RAE sí incluye el sufijo productivo, pero no todas las palabras que se pueden crear así:

> #### [‒́ico, ca](https://dle.rae.es/%E2%80%92%CC%81ico)
>
> 1. suf. Aparece en adjetivos. Indica relación con la base derivativa. *Periodístico, humorístico, alcohólico.* A veces toma la forma [‒́tico](https://dle.rae.es/%E2%80%92%CC%81tico#ZibqWJB). *Sifilítico.*

Como recurso alternativo, [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tan%C3%A1tico) tiene la palabra en sus entradas.

Answer (score 4):

El Diccionario de la Lengua sí recoge [tanato-](https://dle.rae.es/tanato-) como:

> 1. elem. compos. Significa 'muerte'. *Tanatofobia, tanatología.*